# What is the probability of at least 4 events occurring in 6 tries, given that $P(\text{occurring})=0.7$?

Tags: probability

Problem:
The plant is capable of growing seed 70% of the time.
Calculate the probability that out of 6 tries, at least 4 seeds will be grown.

A=seed is grown
$$P(A)=0.7$$
From where do I start with this problem?
Could I use de Moivre-Laplace integral theorem?
$$P(m_1\leq m\leq m_2)=\Phi(x_2)-\Phi(x_1)$$

In my case that would be:
$$P(4\leq X\leq 6)=\Phi(x_2)-\Phi(x_1),$$
$$x_1=\frac{4-6\cdot 0.7}{\sqrt{6\cdot0.7\cdot0.3}}\approx-0.16$$
$$x_2=\frac{6-6\cdot 0.7}{\sqrt{6\cdot0.7\cdot0.3}}\approx1.61$$

Therefore,

$P(4 \leq X \leq 6)=\Phi(0.16)+\Phi(1.61)=0.0636+0.4463=0.5099$

Am I right? Is this the right approach?

Comment: The probability of exactly $k$ events occurring in $6$ tries can be computed using the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). For at least $4$ events occurring, add up the above for $k=4,5,6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approximation by $\Phi$ will give results that are not too unreasonable even with numbers as small as $4$ and $6$ if, but only if, a continuity correction is used.  That means "$\ge 4$" is the same as "$>3$", so you say "$>3.5$" instead.  That gives surprisingly good approximations even with samples as small as this, whereas textbooks usually give more cautious advice that such approximations should be used only when the expected numbers of successes and failures are both at least $5$.  Indeed, even with a sample size of only $1$, the probability you get that way will never be off by more than about $0.03$.

**But all that is pointless** in this case, since in a case like this you can easily get exact answers by knowing about the binomial distribution.  Applying the probability mass function for the binomial distribution, we have
$$
\binom 6 4 0.7^4 (1-0.7)^2 + \binom 6 50.7^5(1-0.7) + \binom 6 60.7^6.
$$

Comment: I'm getting $0.74431$ as the sum of values from the probability mass function, and $0.733558$ for the approximation by the normal distribution, with the continuity correction, just looking at the probability that it's more than $3.5$. ${}\qquad{}$